# Why was the OP's comment deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-comments

The OP posted a comment on [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65307539/263693) indicating that it was indeed the correct solution. I was pretty sure, but not entirely sure, that it would work when I wrote the answer.

Why was that comment deleted?

Comment: presumably because it was no longer needed, since the op accepted it.

Comment: Did it started with *Thanks* ?

Comment: IMO confirmation of the answer working is useful information. I've seen several accepted answers that do not work, so accepted != working.

Comment: It may have started with Thanks. I don't remember and I can't see deleted comments.

Comment: If it started with Thanks then a single flag will delete the comment.

Comment: It was flagged (and your response to it) as no longer needed - a moderator agreed and deleted both comments. They were not needed after the OP accepted your answer.

Comment: My, what a welcoming community Meta is! I'll be sure to be back...

Comment: What's not "welcoming" in your interaction with meta? That some users downvoted the question?

Comment: I've personally flagged hunderds of comments under accepted answers that only added: Thanks, this works. Why would that comment be adding anything more useful then the green thick from the OP?

Comment: @rene https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgdOK.png (Note that both were seen and deleted by a human. Or a dog. You can't tell with [today's mod team](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).)

Comment: @CodyGray THOSE COMMENTS ARE HILARIOUS!!! What a loss!

Comment: @CodyGray You're forgetting that the comments may have been deleted by a pair of glasses ;)

Comment: @JonClements The same happened to me as well. Yesterday I've added some comments to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65321489/1104384), it helped the OP and they said thanks. Today, when I checked all those comments were gone, including the comment which helped the OP. I didn't add any answer or OP didn't accept the answer posted there (The answer posted there was using code from a different post which I've shared in the comments). I was searching on meta to find similar posts and found this one, that's why commenting here. Please help me to understand what happened there. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three possibilities:

1. The OP realized that by accepting your answer, it is already clear that your answer is correct. Therefore, the OP chose to delete the comment.
2. A moderator (possibly from a flag) chose to delete the comment to prevent comment clutter.
3. The comment started with `Thanks!` and thus was automatically deleted after someone flagged it. (Credit to rene for pointing this out!)

In all cases, it has nothing to do with you. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Plus, comments are second class-citizens. They can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 17):

Comments are meant for critique or getting clarification about a post. If and when that feedback has been received and its outcome is, when needed, captured in an edit of the post, the comments are obsolete and no longer needed. That means the comments can be deleted. The preferred way is that the OP delete their own comments but flagging comments can be done by any member with > 15 reputation.

The two comments that were deleted [read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgdOK.png):

> - THAT was it. Saved my day and hair. Thanks a bunch. [Q-OP]
> - Just doing my part to fight developer balding. [A-OP]

While both are witty and certainly fit my style of humor those comments don't bring on anything that relates to the post, at least nothing that can't be expressed better with the accept mark.

It could well have been that a commenter fits next to their *Thanks* extra information relevant to the question or answer in the 500 available characters. If that had been the case, right out deletion had not been the correct moderation action, even the flags should have stayed at bay in that case.

These two comments don't have extra value for the content in the post. That warrants no longer needed flags on them and deletion by a moderator when those flags pop-up in their queue.

Thankfully we have now a meta post so the witty and cheerful comments can live forever.

Answer (score 3):

Why not? The voting (and acceptance) indicates that the majority of voters find the answer helpful, so there doesn't seem to be any particular reason to keep it (especially since you've already seen the comment and know that it worked for the OP).